# Javascript reduce for certain objects within an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dictionary, reduce

I'm having a little problem here with counting array of object values... The code I have below works just fine but what if I want to target only certain objects within the reduce function?

Basically, something like an SQL **WHERE** function, so

```
newcost = Number((cart.map(item => (item.cost * item.amm)).reduce((prev, next) => Number(prev) + Number(next))).toFixed(2));
```

would be

```
newcost = Number((cart.map(item => (item.cost * item.amm)).reduce((prev, next) => Number(prev) + Number(next))).toFixed(2)) WHERE item.type === "c";
```

You know, something similar to this. How can I achieve something like this?

Thank you.

Comment: you could put a `.filter` in between: `x.map().filter(...).reduce(...)`

Comment: @georg how would that look like?

Comment: [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you could do it with `filter()`.  `filter()` returns an array where the function passed to it returns true. This has the effect of only retuning items of type 'c'.

```js
var cart = [
    {type:'c', cost:20.00, amm: 10},
    {type:'d', cost:20.00, amm: 1},
    {type:'d', cost:20.00, amm: 2},
    {type:'c', cost:1.00, amm: 5},
    {type:'a', cost:20.00, amm: 7},

]
let newcost = cart.filter(i => i.type === 'c') // only c type items
                  .map(item => item.cost * item.amm)
                  .reduce((prev, next) => prev + next)
                  .toFixed(2);

console.log(newcost)
```

Also, you didn't ask, but the `map()` call is extraneous — you don't really need it and it causes an extra loop through your data (you could also just do the test in `reduce()` and leave out the `filter()` although that might start to impact readability):

```js
var cart = [
    {type:'c', cost:20.00, amm: 10},
    {type:'d', cost:20.00, amm: 1},
    {type:'d', cost:20.00, amm: 2},
    {type:'c', cost:1.00, amm: 5},
    {type:'a', cost:20.00, amm: 7},

]
let newcost = cart.filter(i => i.type === 'c')
                  .reduce((prev, next) => prev + next.cost * next.amm, 0)
                  .toFixed(2);

console.log(newcost)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add your conditional first in the reduce function. If the element doesn’t match your conditional, just return the accumulator first without modifying it.